# Как сделать чтобы при появлении клавиатуры не было фокуса на EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Ситуация следующая: `Android` приложение. Есть 1 `EditText`, `ImageView` (хотя может быть и другой `view`), есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую появляется клавиатура. Так вот, в идеале надо, чтобы при нажатии кнопки появления клавиатуры, кроме вызова клавиатуры убирался фокус, ввод в `EditText` чтобы в `EditText` прекращали появляться буквы, чтобы они обрабатывались другим методом, и только при нажатии на `EditText` на нем появлялся фокус, и появлялись буквы и шла обработка `EditText`. Например, без `EditText` в моей `Activity` все обрабатывается так:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_UNKNOWN) {
        String s = event.getCharacters();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
            sendChar(s.charAt((i)));
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; ++i)
             onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Но когда я вставляю в `layout Activity EditText` вся обработка прекращается, просто выводятся буквы в `EditText`.

Answer (score 1):

В манифесте

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Еще можете в самом `Edittext` добавить:

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

Третий вариант, добавить в родительский Layout

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

Comment: нет не помогает

Comment: @MadokaMagica добавил ещё один вариант

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю может сделал по тупому, но вроде работает, ставлю на EditText OnClickListener:

```
 etbrw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                etbrw.setFocusable(true);
                etbrw.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            }
        });
```

В обработчике кнопки или картинке просто пишу:

```
etbrw.setFocusable(false);
touchpad.setFocusable(true);
```

Два клика по editText и он выделяется вкл. его обработчик. Клик по кнопке или картинке и фокус с edittext пропадает, начинает работать onKeyMultiple